# How to return the result of dialog window work in the moment of its closing?

Tags: .net, dialog, execution, delay

Everyone knows the MessageBox.Show() method, that returns DialogResult value after dialog closed.
How can I implement such a method in my dialog class?

class MyDialog : Form {

```
public static MyDialogResult Show() {};
```

}

The problem, as you can guess, is that the method returns a value only after user clicks some button in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set the DialogResult property on a button. If that button is clicked then the specified value will be returned by the ShowDialog() method.

Answer (score 0):

In your handler which closes your dialog, put this before closing:

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Or whatever you want the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful answers. Thanks!
But I've solved my problem yet, using mutex. It provides ability to return results of different types. So, my showDialog() method returns a string ).